# What is the technique for effective rocket jumping?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-soldier

Rocket jumping seems to be one of the most important techniques in the Soldier's arsenal.  How is a "good" rocket jump performed?

Comment: It's a great "weapon", but don't over-use it. The health loss is quite important, so don't do it all the time like some people do. It would only leave you with 50 hp in front of the enemy. If you absolutely want to jump repeatedly (like I tend to do), try to unlock the [gunboats](http://www.teamfortress.com/war/victory/).

Comment: Don't forget, you can rocket jump off walls too if you really get good at your timing.

Comment: Actually, the health loss is only 30 or so with the best rocketjump, and if there's a health pack near your destination, you can rocketjump all the way there and still be at almost full health. Just don't forget to reload before going into combat.

Comment: Note: You can practice the timing of Rocket Jumps using the Rocket Jumper weapon, but I don't believe it drops randomly... you have to buy it from the Mann Co. Store.

Comment: @Powerlord It can also be crafted using a class token + slot token + scrap metal.  Granted, this will craft a random soldier primary weapon, but one of the craftable items is indeed the rocket jumper. At the time of this post, there was a 1 in 3 chance for the rocket jumper (you could also receive a direct hit or a black box)

Comment: The Rocket Jumper (and Sticky Jumper) now drops randomly. See http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Rocket_Jumper

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You crouch-jump, and shoot a rocket at your feet.

Make sure you're as far as possible from the ground the moment the rocket hits the ground to make sure you're not damaged too much. The last part might take some practising.

By the way, Valve has included a training weapon in the game called the [Rocket Jumper](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Rocket_Jumper). With it, you get twice the ammo and no self-inflicted damage. It's not useful out in the field, really. It can be crafted or bought in the Mann-Co store for $0.49 / £0.29 / €0.49.

*(Powerlord mentioned this in the comments to the question above)*

Comment: The "crouch" part of the jump is not that obvious, actually. It took me some time to understand that I missed that, to make a full rocket jump.

Comment: Glad to help then. :-) Removed 'simply' to make it sound less condescending.

Comment: Wow, I also had no idea about crouching despite being a "Grizzled Veteran". Mind == blown.

Comment: The extra damage from the Rocket Jumper has been removed.

Answer (score 4):

As Arda Xi mentioned, if you are crouching when the rocket explodes, you will go higher. In some cases, it's best not to crouch when jumping, like when you don't want to over-shoot your target, or to avoid fall damage.

It takes a while to get the timing down between jumping and shooting; there's sort of a sweet-spot. The setup phase is a great time to practice rocket-jumping.

Comment: I've found that not crouching helps for more "lateral" rocket jumps.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question, but I'm surprised no one has mentioned this: Don't press <kbd>W</kbd> or <kbd>s</kbd> during your jump; both of these will cause you to lose momentum very quickly. Use <kbd>a</kbd> and <kbd>d</kbd> to maneuver in the air.

Answer (score 1):

One way to get a consistent rocket jump is to use a [script](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Scripting), which condenses all the key presses into a single command. I provide an example rocket jump script at the end of the post. To use it, copy the text to Steam\steamapps\common\Team Fortress 2\tf\cfg\soldier.cfg and rebind the keys as necessary.

The "alias" lines define the rocket jumping commands (one for regular rocket jump and one for the crouch jump which adds extra height). These lines should not be edited.

The "bind" lines allow you to specify which key you would like to perform the listed action. You can edit the keys according to [this list](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Scripting#List_of_key_names).

```
// Rocket Jump
alias +rocketjump "+jump;wait;+attack"
alias -rocketjump "-jump;-attack"

// Crouching Rocket Jump (Extra Height)
alias +crouchjump "+jump;+duck;wait;+attack"
alias -crouchjump "-jump;-attack;wait;wait;wait;-duck"

// DO NOT EDIT ABOVE THIS LINE

// Bind rocket jump commands
bind "MOUSE4" "+rocketjump"
bind "MOUSE5" "+crouchjump"
```

Comment: Keep in mind that on many servers `wait` time is set to either zero or indefinite.