# Can I rocket jump with a controller on pc?

Tags: team-fortress-2, controllers, tf2-soldier

I often see soldiers flying by overhead to get to the control points quicker. Sometimes I have seen Demomen (though this is really no hard task with Demoman) and sometimes even engineers doing this too. (Only impressive if they aren't using a wrangler, though).

Anyway, I have tried to rocket jump with much failures. I play TF2 on PC with a Xbox 360 controller. How can I rocket jump? Is it possible to do so with a controller?

As an aside: How can I craft a Rocket Jumper?

Comment: You'll find all the necessary informations in the best answer of [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1139/what-is-the-technique-for-effective-rocket-jumping?rq=1).

Comment: Um ok. That really doesn't help. Please be direct with the answer rather than glide around it please. I honestly have no patience with riddles.

Comment: Well then, Research effort : -1

Comment: Why are you using a controller rather than a mouse?

Comment: Because I am using a laptop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make a good rocket jump, you'll need to aim down or even slightly behind, and jump just before shooting.
If you shoot diagonally in front of you, you wont accelerate forward. Think about the propelling force that is pushing you backwards.

The hint of an achievement tells you the way to get the highest jump :

[image: Achievement - highest jump]
Where Eagles Dare
Get the highest possible rocket jump using **jump and crouch**.

For the other question, the [Rocket Jumper](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Rocket_Jumper) can be crafted with :

- 3 Mantreads, and 1 Reclaimed Metal
- Soldier Token + Primary Token + Scrap Metal (1/8 possible results)
- IRL money at Mann-Co Store, for around half a dollar

Answer (score 3):

You can Rocket Jump with a controller, it's just a lot trickier as you can't snap your view around like you can with a mouse.  Since rocket jumping involves aiming down while jumping, view snapping is a vital skill to it.

It's a lot easier to sticky jump with the demoman for this reason, as Demo doesn't have to look down to do it (just remember that 3+ stickies WILL kill you).

As for the Rocket Jumper, you can get it as a random drop these days, so you might want to look into trading with someone for it.

Having said that, it does have a crafting recipe: 3x Mantreads and 1x Reclaimed Metal.  You can find it on the list of crafting recipes under Common Items.

Comment: +1 for mouse flickering. It is really useful in the middle of the battlefield while doing jumps.